# Print N records at a time from a stream

Tags: text-processing, awk

I need to fixup the output of a space separated collection of words. The collection is from a [`GNUmakefile`](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/GNUmakefile) to print the source files used in compilation:

```
$ make sources
Library sources: cryptlib.cpp cpu.cpp integer.cpp 3way.cpp adler32.cpp algebra.c
pp algparam.cpp arc4.cpp aria-simd.cpp aria.cpp ariatab.cpp asn.cpp authenc.cpp
...
```

Using the following `awk` I can break at a single word. It needs a little manual cleanup, but it is otherwise fine for adding to a [`Makefile.am`](https://github.com/noloader/cryptopp-autotools/blob/master/Makefile.am) for Autotools:

```
$ make sources | awk '{print "    " $0 " \\"}' RS=' '
    Library \
    sources: \
    cryptlib.cpp \
    cpu.cpp \
    integer.cpp \
    ...
```

Attempting to extend it to 4 or 8 words is giving me some trouble:

```
$ make sources | awk '{print "    " $0 $1 $2 $3 " \\"}' RS=' '
    LibraryLibrary \
    sources:sources: \
    cryptlib.cppcryptlib.cpp \
    cpu.cppcpu.cpp \
    integer.cppinteger.cpp \
```

My first question is, is `awk the right tool for the job? Or should I be using another tool?

My next question is, how do I print an arbitrary number of records, like 4 or 8, and then break it with a newline?

---

My bad... the desired output is not clear. Given:

```
$ make sources
Library sources: cryptlib.cpp cpu.cpp integer.cpp 3way.cpp adler32.cpp algebra.c
pp algparam.cpp arc4.cpp aria-simd.cpp aria.cpp ariatab.cpp asn.cpp authenc.cpp
```

I want the following, which still requires the fixup (but I am OK with it):

```
$ make sources | awk ...
Library sources: cryptlib.cpp cpu.cpp \
integer.cpp 3way.cpp adler32.cpp algebra.cpp \
algparam.cpp arc4.cpp aria-simd.cpp aria.cpp \
...
```

Once I delete the first two unwanted words, it will look like:

```
$ make sources | awk ...
cryptlib.cpp cpu.cpp \
integer.cpp 3way.cpp adler32.cpp algebra.cpp \
algparam.cpp arc4.cpp aria-simd.cpp aria.cpp \
...
```

Comment: `awk '[...] NR % 4 == 0 { print "" }'`?

Answer (score 1):

Based on discussion in the comments, I believe that what you want to do is write an `awk` expression which takes a string of space-delimited words, removes the first two words, and then prints the remaining words in groups of 4 or 8 per line, with every line (except possibly the last line) ending with a backslash. Consider the following example:

```bsh
echo "a b 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 " | \
cut -d' ' -f3- \
| awk '{printf $0 " "} NR%4==0 {print "\\"}' RS=' '
```

This produces the following output:

```
1 2 3 4 \
5 6 7 8 \
```

Note that I included a space after the last word.

The above command removes the first two words and then prints out the remaining words in groups of 4 words per line, with each line followed by a backslash. Modifying your command to use this approach yields the following:

```bsh
{ make sources; printf ' '; } | \
cut -d' ' -f3- \
| awk '{printf $0 " "} NR%4==0 {print "\\"}' RS=' '
```

Note that I added a space after the output from `make` - just in case.

Since you also asked for potential alternatives to `awk`, I'll mention that I personally would prefer to use Python for this sort of thing. Here's a Python script that should also solve your problem:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2

# chunk.py

import sys

# Read the data from standard input
words = sys.stdin.readline().split()[2:]

# Set the chunk size
n = 4

# Break up the data into chunks
chunks = []
for i in range(0, len(words), n):
    chunks.append(' '.join(words[i:i+n]))

# Print out the reformatted data
print(' \\\n'.join(chunks))
```

Put this in a file (e.g. `chunk.py`) and run it:

```bsh
echo -e "a b 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8" | python chunk.py
```

This produces the following output:

```
1 2 3 4 \
5 6 7 8
```

Comment: My bad... I clarified the question.

Comment: @jww Wait, you want the output to include the backslash characters? Or just four words per line?

Comment: @jww See my updated example. Does that look right to you?

Comment: I did not know `printf` was the way to suppress line endings. I tired a bunch of crazy stuff trying to manipulate `ORS`.

Comment: @jww Ha! Thanks. Handle is fine. I'll clean up my post in a second now that I understand what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks again. That saved over [200 lines in the file](https://github.com/noloader/cryptopp-autotools/commit/80c6f00319e0f4aa).

Comment: @user56041 Why did you unaccept this solution?

Answer (score 1):

A different approach, not using `awk`:

```
 make sources | cut -f2- -d\: | xargs  -n 4 printf '%s %s %s %s \\\n'
```